# How to save multiple values entered into ListBoxField and loop through values?

Tags: silverstripe

I want to be able to associate team members to a project using the `ListBoxField` . I have a `ProjectHolder` which has `Project` pages as it's children. I also have a `TeamHolder` which has `TeamPage`'s as its children.

I want to be able to save multiple team members in the `ListBoxField` and then loop through them on a `Project` page. I also want to be able to link to the team members pages. e.g

```
<% loop $TeamMemberNames %>
    <a href="$Link">$Name</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

***My Current code:***

**TeamPage.php**

```
class TeamPage extends Page
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', TextField::create('Name'));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

**Project.php**

```
class Project extends Page
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', TextField::create('Name'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', ListBoxField::create(
            'TeamPage',
            'Select Team Members for project',
            TeamPage::get()->map("ID", "Name")->toArray()
        )->setMultiple(true));

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I can pull through the names from the `TeamPage` Object into the `ListBoxField` however after selecting the names I need a way to save the multiple values and also get the Link so I can link to the appropriate team members pages that are listed.

Comment: You'll need to define how to save it in Database first. I guess a Member can join many Projects and a Project has many Members, you need a $many_many relation. Did you go through the lessons? http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons The tutorials there should get everything covered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To save data to the database we must first define a relationship to the data in our class. In this case we want to create a `$many_many` relationship between `Project` and `TeamPage`.

In the `Project` class we add a `$many_many` relationship to `TeamPage`. Here, the relationship name is `TeamPages`.

When creating the `ListBoxField` we pass the `TeamPages` relationship name so the field knows where to save this data:

**Project.php**

```
class Project extends Page
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'TeamPages' => 'TeamPage'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', TextField::create('Name'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', ListBoxField::create(
            'TeamPages',
            'Select Team Members for project',
            TeamPage::get()->map('ID', 'Name')->toArray()
        )->setMultiple(true));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Now in our template we can loop through a `Project's` `$TeamPages` by calling the following:

**Template**

```
<% loop $TeamPages %>
    <a href="$Link">$Name</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

If we would like a `TeamPage` to be able to access it's related `Projects` we can add a `$belongs_many_many` to the `TeamPage` class to point back to the `Project` class. You can also add a `ListBoxField` to control `Projects` from the `TeamPage`.

**TeamPage.php**

```
class TeamPage extends Page
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Projects' => 'Project'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', TextField::create('Name'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', ListBoxField::create(
            'Projects',
            'Select project for this team page',
            Project::get()->map('ID', 'Name')->toArray()
        )->setMultiple(true));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Something to note is `TeamPage` and `Project` both extend `Page`. This means both classes inherit a `Title` field. I would suggest using `Title` instead of `Name`, unless you have a specific reason to do so.

This would make the code:

**Project.php**

```
class Project extends Page
{
    private static $many_many = array(
        'TeamPages' => 'TeamPage'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.TeamMembers', ListBoxField::create(
            'TeamPages',
            'Select Team Members for project',
            TeamPage::get()->map('ID', 'Title')->toArray()
        )->setMultiple(true));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

**TeamPage.php**

```
class TeamPage extends Page
{
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Projects' => 'Project'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Projects', ListBoxField::create(
            'Projects',
            'Select project for this team page',
            Project::get()->map('ID', 'Title')->toArray()
        )->setMultiple(true));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<% loop $TeamPages %>
    <a href="$Link">$Title</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is it! Appreciate your time :)